# Any Idea of This China's "Transparent Concrete"?

Tags: civil-engineering, concrete, plastic, highway-engineering, photovoltaics

I am currently make an attempt to make miniaturized version of this China's solar highway on my garage

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zK8FvzI3yDA

Just so i can re-evaluate the performance

However, I am curious with the top-most layer. In various online media source it keeps saying "transparent concrete" (which obviously 100% transparent) while i found none information on the web how to create one (not even scientific paper)

What i got so far is the "translucent" version, using fiber optics. But it's not that "transparent" as you can see in video above..

[image]

My best guess its not concrete at all (although many well-known media source said so), possibly kind of plastic (polycarbonate or sort)...

What do you think? Is it possible to make concrete of that kind?

Comment: 100% transparent - I don't think that is possible.

Comment: I am not expecting 100%, but at least concrete with high transparency as what they do with solar highway @SolarMike

Comment: Translucent would be the correct term here....and it’s likely a plastic aggregate and some kind if resin matrix.

Comment: concrte is by definition sand, stones + cement and neither is translucent so I think you are on the rght track to presume some sort of plastic.

Comment: @mart  Sand and gravel can be made of more or less finely ground glass, mostly translucent. Portland cement is not the only cement in existence either.